# How to write array of objects to a json file with express?

Tags: express

My backend(express) received the data from the client(reactjs) as an array of objects and I want to write the data to a json file, but I fail to do so.

Code that I perform this task :

```
 export const addStatements = async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // form fields
    
    fs.writeFile('./categories.json', JSON.stringify(req.body), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Done writing!")
    })
}
```

Array of objects received from the client :

{
categoryFilename: '[{"description":"GOOGLE","category":"MISC"},{"description":"AMZN","category":"MERCHANDISE"},{"description":"MCDONALD","category":"DINNING"},{"description":"SAFEWAY","category":"GROCERIES"},{"description":"WISH","category":"MERCHANDISE"},{"description":"99 RANCH","category":"GROCERIES"},{"description":"PARKMOBILE","category":"COLLEGE FEE"},{"description":"CITY OF SAN RAMON","category":"TENNIS"},{"description":"FILA","category":"APPAREL"},{"description":"COMCAST","category":"TELECOM"},{"description":"PEETS","category":"COFFEE"}]'
}

Got the json file after it is written by my code:

{"categoryFilename":"[{\"description":\"GOOGLE",\"category\":\"MISC\"},{\"description\":\"AMZN\",\"category\":\"MERCHANDISE\"},{\"description\":\"MCDONALD\",\"category\":\"DINNING\"},{\"description\":\"SAFEWAY\",\"category\":\"GROCERIES\"},{\"description\":\"WISH\",\"category\":\"MERCHANDISE\"},{\"description\":\"99 RANCH\",\"category\":\"GROCERIES\"},{\"description\":\"PARKMOBILE\",\"category\":\"COLLEGE FEE\"},{\"description\":\"CITY OF SAN RAMON\",\"category\":\"TENNIS\"},{\"description\":\"FILA\",\"category":\"APPAREL\"},{\"description\":\"COMCAST\",\"category":\"TELECOM\"},{\"description\":\"PEETS\",\"category":\"COFFEE\"}]"}

The json file that I want :

[
{
"description":"GOOGLE",
"category": "MISC"
},
{
"description":"AMZN",
"category":"MERCHANDISE"
},
{
"description":"MCDONALD",
"category":"DINNING"
},
{
"description":"SAFEWAY",
"category":"GROCERIES"
},
{
"description":"WISH",
"category":"MERCHANDISE"
},
{
"description":"99 RANCH",
"category":"GROCERIES"
},
{
"description":"PARKMOBILE",
"category":"COLLEGE FEE"
},
{
"description":"CITY OF SAN RAMON",
"category":"TENNIS"
},
{
"description":"FILA",
"category":"APPAREL"
},
{
"description:"COMCAST",
"category":"TELECOM"
},
{
"description:"PEETS",
"category":"COFFEE"
}
]

Comment: Sounds like it's a string. Are you using JSON parsing middleware? It seems not. Maybe remove the `JSON.stringify()` call. You can try `typeof req.body` to see what it is. The comment says "form fields" but the log doesn't look like form data at all, so it's all a bit confusing. Suggest a [mcve] and clarity.

Comment: Tried to remove JSON.stringify(), but got the following complain: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array.   Tried to use the JSON.parse, not succeeded as well.

Comment: Looking closer, try skipping `JSON.stringify` still, but write this: `req.body.categoryFilename`. It appears that the payload is being parsed as JSON, but its child value wasn't stringified correctly, so that's still an unparsed JSON blob. Basically a problem with how the frontend is building the request payload which you should probably fix rather than the workaround I'm suggesting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I got the following result with my own express server.

```js
fs.writeFile('./categories.json', req.body.categoryFilename, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Done writing!")
});
```

Result from `categories.json` file.

```
[
    {
        "description": "GOOGLE",
        "category": "MISC"
    },
    {
        "description": "AMZN",
        "category": "MERCHANDISE"
    },
    {
        "description": "MCDONALD",
        "category": "DINNING"
    },
    {
        "description": "SAFEWAY",
        "category": "GROCERIES"
    },
    {
        "description": "WISH",
        "category": "MERCHANDISE"
    },
    {
        "description": "99 RANCH",
        "category": "GROCERIES"
    },
    {
        "description": "PARKMOBILE",
        "category": "COLLEGE FEE"
    },
    {
        "description": "CITY OF SAN RAMON",
        "category": "TENNIS"
    },
    {
        "description": "FILA",
        "category": "APPAREL"
    },
    {
        "description": "COMCAST",
        "category": "TELECOM"
    },
    {
        "description": "PEETS",
        "category": "COFFEE"
    }
]
```

Comment: I skipped JSON.stringify and write this: req.body.categoryFilename solves the problem. Thanks anyway!